# XNA projects hosted in Dropbox fails to build due to incorrect file paths

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna, dropbox

I have an XNA project that's hosted and shared with another user via a Dropbox account.  When I try to build, it fails with this error:

Unable to copy file "D:\Documents\Dropbox\Super Mario Limitless\SuperMarioLimitless\SuperMarioLimitless\bin\x86\Debug\Content\m_norm.xnb" to "bin\x86\Debug\m_norm.xnb". Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Documents\Dropbox\Super Mario Limitless\SuperMarioLimitless\SuperMarioLimitless\bin\x86\Debug\Content\m_norm.xnb'.

It seems to be trying to pull a file out of the other computer's path, which clearly doesn't exist on this computer.  I've traced it down (roughly) to a file called ContentPipeline.xml in $(SolutionFolder)\SuperMarioLimitlessContent\obj\x86\Debug\

```
  <Item>
      <Source>m_norm.png</Source>
      <Name>m_norm</Name>
      <Importer>TextureImporter</Importer>
      <Processor>TextureProcessor</Processor>
      <Options>None</Options>
      <Output>D:\Documents\Dropbox\Super Mario Limitless\SuperMarioLimitless\SuperMarioLimitless\bin\x86\Debug\Content\m_norm.xnb</Output>
      <Time>2012-12-06T21:47:30-05:00</Time>
  </Item>
```

Now, I can change the paths to my own, and it will work for me but not for him.  I tried changing them to relative paths, but it doesn't seem like whatever's loading this file will parse relative paths, nor does it work with $(SolutionFolder) or $(ProjectFolder), instead interpreting them literally.

The two content files in question are both set to "Build Action: Compile" and "Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always".

So, is there a way to fix this, or is this a sign of deeper problems?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Combining "Compile" and "Copy to Output Directory" usually doesn't make sense.

Comment: I've tried "Content" but that didn't change anything, either.

Comment: If the expected output is an XNB file then it probably should be in a content project and set to "Compile" and "Do not copy". However I suspect this isn't the root cause of your problem. Can you explain more how your project is set up? Normally content is referenced in a `.contentproj` file, which in turn is referenced from a `.csproj` file (which is what actually gets built). The existence of your `ContentPipeline.xml` file in what should be an output directory seems unusual to me. If it is really an output, it should be safe to delete the file (perhaps it's caching the wrong directory).